# C# DataTable returns error result while using Select function

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

We used DataTable.Select function in our project to get dynamic results, but we encountered an unexpected result yesterday. So I make a simple test C# program shown below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ENTERPRISE_CODE", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UNIT_HEIGHT", typeof(decimal)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("COMMENTS", typeof(string)));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ENTERPRISE_CODE"] = "BS_CS";
    dr["UNIT_HEIGHT"] = 12;
    dr["COMMENTS"] = "Inside 11.5K";

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();

    string filter1 = "(comments not like '%shaping%' and comments not like '%modelling%' and (comments not like '%doing%' and comments not like '%11.5k%' and comments not like '%drilling%'))";
    string filter2 = "enterprise_code = 'BS_CS' and " + filter1;
    string filter3 = "unit_height = 12 and " + filter1;
    string filter4 = "unit_height <> 13 and " + filter1;
    
    int count11 = dt.Select(filter1).Length; // returns no rows, correctly
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter1;
    int count12 = dt.DefaultView.Count;      // returns no rows, correctly

    int count21 = dt.Select(filter2).Length; // returns 1 row, wrongly
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter2;
    int count22 = dt.DefaultView.Count;      // returns no rows, correctly

    int count31 = dt.Select(filter3).Length; // returns 1 row, wrongly
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter3;
    int count32 = dt.DefaultView.Count;      // returns no rows, correctly

    int count41 = dt.Select(filter4).Length; // returns no rows, correctly
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter4;
    int count42 = dt.DefaultView.Count;      // returns no rows, correctly

    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
}
```

I insert one row to my test DataTable with "Inside 11.5K" in column "COMMENTS". The DataTable is set with unsensitive case, so it should return false while filtered using "comments not like '%11.5k%'". DataTable.Select returns no results using 'filter1' as i expected.

However, when i add condition "enterprise_code = 'BS_CS'" or "unit_height = 12" to 'filter1', the returned result is not as expected. What confuses me more is that different results returned while using "unit_height = 12" or "unit_height <> 13" as an additional condition.

Is there anyone knows how the above problem caused?

I also make a SQL test using SSMS. The results are correct, no rows returned for each query.

```
create table Test
(
  [ENTERPRISE_CODE] nvarchar(50) null,
  [UNIT_HEIGHT] decimal(18, 2) null,
  [COMMENTS] nvarchar(50) null
);

insert into Test
select 'BS_CS', 12, 'Inside 11.5K';

select * from Test where (comments not like '%shaping%' and comments not like '%modelling%' and (comments not like '%doing%' and comments not like '%11.5k%' and comments not like '%drilling%'));
-- returns no rows
select * from Test where enterprise_code = 'BS_CS' and (comments not like '%shaping%' and comments not like '%modelling%' and (comments not like '%doing%' and comments not like '%11.5k%' and comments not like '%drilling%'));
-- returns no rows
select * from Test where unit_height = 12 and (comments not like '%shaping%' and comments not like '%modelling%' and (comments not like '%doing%' and comments not like '%11.5k%' and comments not like '%drilling%'));
-- returns no rows
select * from Test where unit_height <> 13 and (comments not like '%shaping%' and comments not like '%modelling%' and (comments not like '%doing%' and comments not like '%11.5k%' and comments not like '%drilling%'));
-- returns no rows
```

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Profiler or a simpler tool like ExpressProfiler to capture the query that's being executed?  If so, can you please include the query that .NET is executing in your answer?  It sounds possible that there's a bug here; profiling the query is the best way to verify that that's the case.

Comment: I have tried using SQL Server (case-unsensitive) to excute the same four queries, no rows are returned.@pbarranis

Comment: That's mysterious.  So, you're saying, if you completely eliminate use of datatables and reconstruct this entire problem in raw SQL in SSMS, it still occurs?  If so, can you post the complete raw query(ies) you executed please?

Comment: Sorry, i did not describe clearly before. The results SSMS returned are correct. No rows are returned for each query mentioned in my question. However, when using DataTable, rows are returned with 'filter2' or 'filter3'. I have re-edited my question and posted the SQL test query.

Comment: I made a different test with DataView. The return results are correctly by using DataView.RowFilter.